# How does "Protect" work?

Tags: support, protected-questions

Going through Review (Low Quality, usually) I occasionally run across questions that are supposedly "protected" from having contributions made by users with less than 10 reputation points. But I'm usually having to review an Answer from someone with less reputation, and that contribution is rarely of any useful quality. Example:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11251021

Under what circumstances is the "protection" not in force?

Comment: That user had > 10 reputation at the time they answered. Protection does not retroactively remove old answers.

Comment: 15K Privilege: [protect questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions)

Comment: <thunk> (sound of head hitting monitor). Logical. Sometimes hard to realize how "interactive" this site is! Thanks to all for the quick response :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Under what circumstances is the "protection" not in force?

Never.  The user had more than 10 reputation when they posted their answer, but the upvoted was later reversed, putting them below 10 reputation.

Comment: The darn 5 seconds...

Comment: @Zizouz212 That and your assertion that he went below 10 rep from downvotes is incorrect.  The only answer upvote he ever got was reversed when a user was deleted.

Comment: @Servy Ah, I just looked at the profile and saw the rep decrease in the graph, so that's all I assumed :/

Answer (score 4):

Protection forces answers to questions to be made by users with more than 10 rep. You've got that part sorted out.

What you encountered in the low quality queue was an answer made by somebody that at had 10 reputation *at the time the user answered*. The user went below 10 rep afterwards.

If you go below 10 rep, the system will not automatically delete the answer. For all we know, the answer could have merit.